# Passing Variables from User Control to User Control

Tags: c#, winforms

I need a way to pass user control to user controls.

I am using Windows Forms.

For example. Say I have a radiobutton in User control 1 and I want User Control 2 to call and see if that radiobutton is checked on User control 1. How would I reference that?

And for some sample code:

> This is UserControl1

```
public void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

> This is UserControl2

```
 private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

            if (radioButton1.Checked)
               //do something
            else
               //do something
        }
```

Comment: How userControl1 related to userControl2? Is it child control or not? Or both controls used on your form independently? Also is it WebForms or WInForms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you have two unrelated user controls on your form. And UserControl2 (UC2) should change it's behavior is something happens on UserControl1 (UC1). That means you should have an *event* on UC1 which will fire if radiobutton1 checked state changes. You also will need to expose radiobutton status. You can do it either with custom EventArgs or with public property:

> UserControl1

```
public event EventHandler SomethingChanged;

private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (SomethingChanged != null)
       SomethingChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}

public bool IsSomethingEnabled => radioButton1.Checked;
```

UC2 should allow changing it's behavior. That can be done with public property

> UserControl2

```
public bool UseCoolFeature { get; set; }

private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (UseCoolFeature)
       //do something
    else
       //do something else
}
```

And last step - coordinator which will manage both usercontrols. It's your form. Subscribe to event from UC1 and change state of UC2:

> Form

```
private void userControl1_SomethinChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    userControl2.UseCoolFeature = ((UserControl1)sender).IsSomethingEnabled;
}
```

You can even use in-place event handler:

```
userControl1.SomethingChanged += (s,e) =>
     userControl2.UseCoolFeature = userControl1.IsSomethingEnabled;
```

Comment: This is not transferring still. Do I have to add something into UserControl2?

Comment: @user7427899 can you answer to my questions please

Comment: I am confused about what you mean by that? I am guessing you mean I have to reference "IsSomethingEnabled" in UserControl2?

Comment: @user7427899 how UC1 related to UC2?

Comment: UC1 Contains a Radio button that effects a button's actions on UC2.

Comment: Thanks! But    "if (SomethingChanged != null)
       SomethingChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);" is giving me errors

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133502/discussion-between-user7427899-and-sergey-berezovskiy).

Answer (score -2):

You can store the value in your session:

> UserControl1

```
public void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["radioButton1Checked"] = radioButton1.Checked;
}
```

> UserControl2

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["radioButton1Checked"] != null && (bool)Session["radioButton1Checked"])
       //do something
    else
       //do something
}
```

Comment: Session does not exist in the current context.

Comment: My bad, I thought of asp usercontrols... Please add your technology, like winforms, asp or something...

Comment: this suggestion is for asp.net webforms